# Wordpress functions not working custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I've created a page called "page-myslug".

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: myslug
*/
```

I see that in the back-office, but when I go to the page through url (so www.mywp.com/wp-content/themes/site/page-myslug.php?value=4243 => value=4243 because my page is for create PDF, it's not WordPress in the proper way). I have an error message saying that my functions aren't defined (I used them to create url to display PDF thanks to TCPDF). It's working if I add :

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

But it's clearly not recommanded, so what can I do to fix that?

Comment: What is the readout of your exact error?

Comment: where you creating the template file? Is this page in your current theme? Please be more specific in question so can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to create pages in that way. Instead do it in a wordpress way....
Your pdf generation link should look like : `yoursite.com?create_pdf=1`

not in your theme's functions.php write code -

```
add_action('init', 'create_pdf_file');

function create_pdf_file(){
  if(isset($_POST['create_pdf'])){
     // Do your pdf printing task
     exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the error, I wasn't using Wordpress page system.
I don't understand, I need to get the ID of the PDF, I need to use $_GET, right ?

Comment: so do i need your function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
 add_action('init', 'create_pdf_file');

    function create_pdf_file(){
      if(isset($_REQUEST['create_pdf'])){
         // Do your pdf printing task
         exit;
      }
    }
```

OR

```
add_action('init', 'create_pdf_file');

    function create_pdf_file(){
      if(isset($_GET['create_pdf'])){
         // Do your pdf printing task
         exit;
      }
    }
```